# Powershell for each line within variable

Tags: powershell, parsing

I am trying to go through a variable, line by line, and apply regex to parse the string within it.

I am downloading the data via invoke-restmethod and am trying to do the below

```
$result= invoke-restmethod -uri $uri -method get

foreach($line in $result)
if($line -match $regex)
{
   #parsing
}
```

the above doesn't work as their is only one line. But when I output result into a file and then apply the above logic it works, like so

```
$result= invoke-restmethod -uri $uri -method get
$result >> $filelocation

$file = get-content $file
foreach($line in $file)
if($line -match $regex)
{
   #parsing
}
```

The script is time critical so I don't have the luxury to write to a file and then reopen, how could I achieve the above without using get-content?

Comment: I want to see the content of the file when you are storing in file and also the content output when you are not storing .Just give a write-host in the loop to get the output in the console and request you to post it.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a problem with Invoke-Method. The following works exactly as you would want.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/feed/
$result | %{ Write-Host $_ }
```

I suspect that the REST endpoint is giving you a UNIX newline instead of a windows newline. In UNIX, a new line is one character 'lf' (line feed). In windows a newline is a 'crlf' (carriage return, line feed).

Try a string split method

```
$result.Split("`n") | %{ Write-Host $_ }
```

or if you prefer your 'foreach' syntax

```
foreach ($line in $result.Split("`n")) {
  Write-Host $line
}
```

[Edit: changed 'for' to 'foreach']

Comment: the second option worked, but i had to change the for to a foreach